Finding the most empty region in a graph?
Suppose I have this network graph (created in R):
library(igraph)


n <- 50

g <- make_tree(n, 2)
g <- add_edges(g, as.vector(t(matrix(sample(1:n, 40, replace=TRUE), ncol=2))))
g <- as.undirected(simplify(g))

colors <- sample(c("white", "#FFB6C6", "#ADD8E6"), n, prob=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2), replace=TRUE)

plot(g,
     vertex.color = colors,
     vertex.size = 15,          
     vertex.label = 1:n,
     vertex.label.cex = 0.6,   
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     edge.width = 0.8,          
     edge.color = "#80808080",  
     layout = layout_with_fr)


Using this graph, I have the following questions:

How would we find the most white (i.e. empty) regions of this graph?
How would we find the most red regions of this graph?
How would we find the most blue regions of this graph?

In graph theory, are there are any measures that can be used to analyze these kinds of problems?
E.g.

I am a blue person (that likes other blue people) and I want to find an empty (i.e. white) spot on this graph closest to the most blue people?
I am a red person (that does not like other red people) and I want to find an empty spot (i.e. white) on this graph farthest away to most red people?
I am a very social person and I want to find an empty spot (i.e. white) on this graph that is the least isolated?
I am a very anti-social person and I want to find an empty spot (i.e. white) on this graph that is the most isolated?


> dput(g)
structure(list(50, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 34, 35, 
35, 36, 37, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 41, 42, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 
46, 46, 47, 48, 48, 49, 49), c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 6, 2, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 13, 9, 18, 9, 14, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
3, 12, 23, 12, 16, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 15, 16, 5, 17, 
17, 2, 18, 18, 19, 19, 14, 20, 20, 21, 21, 33, 39, 6, 22, 22, 
26, 23, 23, 28, 24, 28), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, list(c(1, 0, 
1), list(name = "Tree", children = 2, mode = "out"), structure(list(), names = character(0)), 
    structure(list(), names = character(0))), <environment>), class = "igraph")
> dput(colors)
c("#FFB6C6", "#ADD8E6", "#FFB6C6", "#FFB6C6", "#ADD8E6", "white", 
"#FFB6C6", "white", "#FFB6C6", "#FFB6C6", "#ADD8E6", "#FFB6C6", 
"#ADD8E6", "white", "white", "#ADD8E6", "#FFB6C6", "white", "white", 
"white", "#FFB6C6", "#FFB6C6", "white", "white", "#ADD8E6", "#FFB6C6", 
"white", "white", "#ADD8E6", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"#FFB6C6", "white", "#FFB6C6", "#FFB6C6", "#FFB6C6", "#FFB6C6", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "#FFB6C6", "white", 
"white", "#ADD8E6", "#FFB6C6", "#FFB6C6")


A possible definition of a region: Each node is plotted along with its 1st degree neighbors and 2nd degree neighbors
library(igraph)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

# Function to plot neighborhood of a node
plot_neighborhood <- function(g, node, colors, main_title) {
    neighbors_1 <- neighbors(g, node)
    neighbors_2 <- unique(unlist(sapply(neighbors_1, function(x) neighbors(g, x))))
    neighbors_2 <- setdiff(neighbors_2, c(node, neighbors_1))
    
    nodes_to_keep <- c(node, neighbors_1, neighbors_2)
    sub_g <- induced_subgraph(g, nodes_to_keep)
    
    plot(sub_g,
         vertex.color = colors[nodes_to_keep],
         vertex.size = ifelse(nodes_to_keep == node, 20, 20),
         vertex.label = nodes_to_keep,
         vertex.label.cex = 0.6,
         vertex.label.color = "black",
         edge.color = "#80808080",
         edge.width = 0.8,
         main = paste("Node", node),
         layout = layout_with_fr)
}

par(mfrow=c(5,10), mar=c(0,0,1,0))

for(i in 1:50) {
    plot_neighborhood(g, i, colors, paste("Node", i))
}



What are "regions" of a graph, to you?

It seems as though you aren't really asking about the graph, but about one particular embedding of it in the plane. Is that correct?

Very hard to understand what a region is...

Hi everyone! Thank you for looking at this question. I myself do not know how to properly define a "region" in this graph ... One idea that comes to mind: Pick each node and consider its 1st degree and 2nd degree neighbors as a region?

Search for centrality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closeness_centrality, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality
